# Autoregressive parameter from autocorrelation using R

Tags: r, autocorrelation, correlation

I was wondering how to get autoregressive (AR) parameter ("rho") from an autocorrelation plot using R. Below I generated a correlated data and then provided a simple approach to produce an autocorrelation plot for the data.

```
#load packages
require(spatial)
require(MASS)
library(gstat)
require(rgdal)
require(sp)
#grid
xy <- expand.grid(1:100, 1:100)
names(xy) <- c("x","y")

# create spatially autocorrelated data
g <- gstat(formula=z~1, locations=~x+y, dummy=T, beta=1, 
           model=vgm(psill=0.1, model="Exp", range=10), nmax=10)

# simulate
yy <- predict(g, newdata=xy, nsim=1)
coordinates(yy)=~x+y
spplot(yy, col.regions = rainbow(7)) #plot

#derive autocorrelation structure
a<-data.frame(yy)
colnames(a)<-c("x","y","z") 
a <- surf.ls(2, a) #fits a trend surface by least-squares
cc<-correlogram(a, 100, xlim=c(0,100), ylab="Autocorr", 
                xlab="Distance") #plot correlogram
cc #details
```

The last plot is indicative of an AR-model- the plot indicates autocorrelation coefficient as a function of distance, d; what I'm seeking is the autoregressive parameter ("rho" (values between -1 and +1)) from this AR model, which is indicative of the strength of autocorrelation. The relation between "rho" and correlation coefficient is defined by the following (self-explanatory) equation:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to spatially lag your variable for an autoregressive model an alternative is the `autocov_dist` in the spdep package. For more complex representation of spatial structure, that could be used in something like a mixed effects model, then you could create a design matrix that represents the pair-wise spatial relationship or covariance structure. You really do not need a spatially lagged Moran's-I for an autoregressive model.

Here is a simple example for deriving an inverse distance weighted autocovariance term using the meuse dataset.

Add the libraries and meuse data.

```
library(sp)
library(spdep)
data(meuse)
coordinates(meuse) <- ~x+y
```

Derive optimal bandwidth, autocovariance term and evaluate lags.

```
k.nn <- spdep::knn2nb(spdep::knearneigh(coordinates(meuse)))
  bw <- max(unlist(spdep::nbdists(k.nn, coordinates(meuse))))
( AutoCov <- spdep::autocov_dist(meuse@data[,"copper"], xy = coordinates(meuse), 
                                 nbs = bw, style = "W", type = "inverse") )

nbd <- nbdists(k.nn, coordinates(meuse))                               
gl <- lapply(nbd, function(x) 1/x)
lw <- nb2listw(k.nn, glist=gl)
lags <- lag(lw, meuse$copper) 
all.equal(lags, AutoCov)
```

Just remember that one should evaluate the correlation structure of an autoregressive model. If the spatial lag term is correlated with the *x* side of the equation then the model is quite unstable. Ideally, one should solve the model in an MCMC framework.

Comment: Not sure I understood properly ... is the "Mean relative difference: 0.2864687" is the correlation parameter for copper data? As I read more, I think a pure simultaneous spatial autoregressive (SAR) model: Y = pWY + ε, is needed where the georeferenced variable Y, spatial weights matrix W, and random error ε  can be used to quantify the degree of spatial autocorrelation p (on a scale of 0 to 1)?